# entity class is not getting recognize ! why?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

When ever i try to use my entity class it return me an error like 
so:

> Attempted to load class "test_class" from namespace "MyBundle\Entity".

Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;
use MyBundle\Entity\test_class;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
```

So when i try to use my entity class like so it always return me that error.

But when i click my "test_class()" it open test_class.php file.

That means the name space is right.

```
  $tst = new test_class();
```

this is my entity class --

```
namespace MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * test_class
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class test_class{ ....
```

Do anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You have to name your class in UpperCase. The file name should be TestClass.php, and the class name should be TestClass, and NOT test_class.

Comment: @MeuhMeuh thanks a lot, i will try that now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MeuhMeuh (comments above) is right. I am just posting this as an answer for the sake of formatting.

You should follow [PascalCasing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) convention when naming your classes. Nobody will force you but that is a good practice.

On the other hand, having `_` within the class name is **particullary bad** since, as per PSR-0 standard, it is interpreted as `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` (**[source](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/#underscores-in-namespaces-and-class-names)**)